# First prime of the form $x_i$ for $x_0=658$ and $x_i=1+2x_{i-1}$

Tags: prime-numbers

Given an initial integer $x_0>0$, one can consider the first prime of the recursive sequence $x_i=1+2x_{i-1}$.

Naïvely such a prime should exist for $x_0$ arbitrary since the sequence $\log(x_i)$ is asymptotically
an arithmetic progression. Sometimes it takes however some
time: for $x_0=147$ my Maple algorithm stops when hitting a 771-digit number
labelled as prime by Maple (Maple does not use a primality proof but
some strong primality tests if I am not mistaken).

Starting with $x_0=658$ I lost patience: No prime among the first
$56000$ iterates leading to numbers with almost $17000$ digits.

I tried to find an easy reason: If $x\longmapsto 2x+1$
is $k$-periodic for $k$ prime numbers $p_0,\dotsc,p_{k-1}$ such that $x_i\equiv 0\pmod{p_i}$ and $x_i>p_i$ then there is obviously no prime in this sequence. Such an easy argument fails for all small values of $k$ for the sequence $x_0=658,\dotsc$.

Perhaps my patience ran out a bit early and the sequence will hit
eventually a prime:

*Does an integral sequence given by $x_0>0$, $x_i=1+2x_{i-1}$ necessarily contain a prime number?*

Comment: I second the proposal for a 'procastination' tag. That's what I am doing at this very moment.

Comment: Welcome to the club!

Comment: I was not sure what was the intended meaning of the parenthesis "Maple does not a primality proof but
some strong primality tests if I am not mistaken", but I guessed it missed the word "use".  I hope that this was correct.

Comment: Explicit formula is $659\cdot 2^i-1$, right? This should accelerate a search not considering numbers for which small divisors exist

Comment: @FedorPetrov : Indeed.

Comment: Since the tag (procrastination) was mentioned here, I'll add a link to the relevant thread on meta: [Creation of "procrastination" tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5524).

Comment: This turns out to be false for $x_0$ = 509202.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The $n$th term of your sequence is $x_{n} = 659 \cdot 2^{n} - 1$. People have long searched for prime values of numbers $k \cdot 2^{n} - 1$ for small $k$, with the goal of proving that $k = 509203$ is the *smallest* positive integer for which $k \cdot 2^{n} - 1$ is composite for all $n$. (This is called the Riesel problem.)

According to the MathWorld entry on [Riesel numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RieselNumber.html), in 2004 Dave Linton discovered that $659 \cdot 2^{800516} - 1$ is prime, and that $800516$ is the smallest $n$ so that $659 \cdot 2^{n} - 1$ is prime. A lot of patience would have been required indeed.

Currently, the smallest $k$ for which it is unknown if $k \cdot 2^{n} - 1$ is ever prime is $k = 23669$ and a distributed computing project related to this is run by [PrimeGrid](https://www.primegrid.com/stats_trp_llr.php). For $k = 23669$ all $n < 13968972$ have been tested.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks Jeremy.

Comment: There is a similar project for numbers of the form $k2^n+1$. Keyphrases: Sierpinski number, Seventeen or Bust. Website: http://www.primegrid.com/forum_thread.php?id=1647